# How to return a tuple containing a None value from the C API?

Tags: python, python-c-api

What is the appropriate way to return a tuple containing a `None` value from a C extension to Python? I know that a single `None` value can be created using

```
result = Py_BuildValue("");
```

and that a tuple can be created using something like

```
result = Py_BuildValue("(ii)", 123, 456);
```

but I do not see a way to combine this to get, for example, a tuple containing a proper integer and a `None` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only ever one `None` object in Python, and you can always refer to it in C as [`Py_None`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html).

The code...

```
result = Py_BuildValue("");
```

...just increments the refcount of `Py_None` and returns its pointer, so it's the same as...

```
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
result = Py_None;
```

If you just want to return `None`, then use...

```
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
return Py_None;
```

...or, since Python 2.4, you can do the same thing with a macro...

```
Py_RETURN_NONE;
```

If you return it in a tuple, like this...

```
return Py_BuildValue("(O)", Py_None);
```

...there's no need to increment the refcount - [`Py_BuildValue()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue) does that for you.

But if you return it in a tuple like this...

```
PyObject* tuple = PyTuple_New(1);
Py_INCREF(Py_None);
PyTuple_SetItem(tuple, 0, Py_None);
return tuple;
```

...then you have to increment the refcount, because [`PyTuple_SetItem()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html#PyTuple_SetItem) doesn't do it for you.

Comment: Is the explicit reference counting increment required when using `Py_BuildValue("(O)", Py_None)`? The [documentation of `Py_BuildValue()`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue) for `O` states: *Pass a Python object untouched (except for its reference count, which is incremented by one)*

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Sorry. I rechecked the docs, and accidentally read the wrong section, updated the answer, then realized the error, and reverted the answer.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Updated answer again. FWIW, the latter approach will be marginally faster, because it doesn't have to parse a format string.

Answer (score 3):

```
result = Py_BuildValue("(isi)", 123, NULL, 456);
```

Ref.: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue

Comment: ...or `Py_BuildValue("(iOi)", 123, Py_None, 456)`

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Sorry for un-accepting your answer, I acted too quickly. I accepted Aya's answer because it seems more appropriate. Using a `NULL` string feels somewhat like a hack to me.